# Filtering an object using lodash

Tags: javascript, filtering, lodash

I have a object with many objects in it.

Keys of the objects are some Id's.
And looking like this:
[image]

How can I filter them out, using `lodash` npm.

Comment: `12321cas123sa123` is not an array index. It might be a property name, but it's not an [array index](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#array-index). I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. Could you add a minimal example of the actual array/object and the end result you want to get? That would probably clarify it a lot.

Comment: what about using a Map?

Comment: Ohh, my fault, all the time i was thinking it as a array.. They are actually objects with unique name and arrays let me edit my question.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear enough. Do you want only the unique keys or you want the whole object i.e, key-value pairs? Some sample output would be helpful.

Comment: I edited the subject now.  I want to filter them with lodash,  I dunno do you know the filtering method with lodash.  Here is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5P6LIjQZEU&t=300s at 7:00..  I want to achieve same result if its possible ofc